# Command prompt in nautilus window

Tags: apt, upgrade, nautilus, nautilus-script

I am on an Acer Aspire 5920, running Ubuntu 12.04 32 bit.

Earlier, by mistake, I exited a terminal during:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

The computer said there were internal errors, and I should restart. So I did, and it restarted fine, but now when I open a folder with nautilus it has a command prompt at the top of the folder, everything else displays fine, just the addition of command prompt.

I also install `nautilus-terminal` for the right click - open in terminal feature.

1- Is this a new feature of nautilus-terminal or a bug from closing the terminal by mistake?

2- If it is a bug, how do I fix it?

3- If it isn't a bug, should I do anything to be sure I didn't do anything to damage my file system by exiting:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

4- if it is a bug, how can I suggest to the developers of nautilus or nautilus-terminal this as a feature?

screenshot of nautilus:
[image: screenshot of nautilus with terminal prompt inside]

screenshot of terminal running command:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a && sudo apt-get -f install
```

[image: screenshot of terminal - running command - sudo dpkg --configure -a && sudo apt-get -f install]

Comment: i have done so, no changes to they system nor to nautilus says there is no errors. If it is a new nautilus-terminal feature i dont mind it, could make things easier at times, i just want to be sure it isn't a bug...

Comment: ok, i added a shot of the command being ran, and of nautilus with the prompt inside of it

Answer (score 1):

Ok, since your question has several questions, lets answer them in order:

1. If you install the script `nautilus-terminal` that the expected behavior.
2. No, is not a bug.
3. Is not recommended that you do that. Better use the update manager, or run in another terminal.
4. It's already a feature.

Comment: thank you, ahd on #3 i did that by mistake, new i should not exit from terminal, but was asking is there anything i should do to be sure that did not damage my system, as i am having no errors from it, i do not think that it did, but once before that happened and my computer crashed from the upgrade not finishing, so i know it can damage your system, i wondered if there was anything that i could do that would be sure it did not damage it

Comment: Ubuntu is continueing to tell me it is having internal errors, it has yet to cause any problems beyond the pop up that says it is, just the same i figure i should try to do something to correct this

Comment: @John if your system is having more problems, that is another thing altogether. You should open a new question. I answered your doubts expressed in your question.